# Connecting to a secure webdav server through https

Tags: security, webdav

I'm trying to connect to a secure WebDAV server but I keep getting the error "org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply"

> DBus error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a
>   reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a
>   reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply
>   timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.

How can I check the security policy or furthur diagnose the problem?  I am connected through windows machines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the URI you connect to is like this:

For SSL (https):

```
davs://[username@]servername.tld/folder
```

If not encrypted (http):

```
dav://[username@]servername.tld/folder
```

AFAIK, most webdav servers can only access known folders, they don't support browsing from the root up. Also, the webdav user may be a different one than your current user.

If you don't mind having some xfce dependencies on board, the `gigolo` package will give you a bookmark editor for such links.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem by circumventing it using davfs2 and mounting by command line and fstab rather than going through gnome.

Answer (score 1):

The error was fixed for me by deleting the saved information for the webdav location from the keyring/ Passwords & Encryption key program.

1. Use **Applications** -> **Accessories** -> **Passwords**... or search for passwords in launcher and delete the user/password info.
2. Retry to connect.